# how to handle IShellFolder menu with different folders or ShellExecuteEx with multiple files

Tags: c++, shell, delphi

there are many ansers in the web for this questions, but I couldn't find a solution.

f.e. two files: 'C:\user\doc1.pdf', 'C:\custom\doc.pdf'

for the first file: when requesting relative "IShellfolder _fld1" which points to the whole path "C:\user" and get the PIDLIST with "_fld1.ParseDisplayName(..., 'doc1.pdf', ...)"
then the Menu will display ALL menu-items like in Explorer.
f.e. (Adobe installed) I get "Open with Adobe Acrobat DC".

But when using abolute Path to Desktop, e.g. "IShellfolder _root" and querying PIDList with "_root.ParseDisplayName(..., 'C:\user\doc1.pdf', ...)" then no error occures, some menu-items (f.e. "copy") are shown, but some (f.e. "Open with Adobe Acrobat DC") are missing.

Same wrong behaviour when trying drive path: "IShellfolder _top" references "C:\" and "_root.ParseDisplayName(..., 'user\doc1.pdf', ...)"

Do I have always to take the full directory path to show all items?

========

In all that cases the standard(!) menu items like "copy" work, so I can copy files from total different directories (also network drives) at once and paste somewhere in explorer in one step. great.

========

but specific menus:
There are multiple websites which talk about merging menus by myself and use "ShellExecuteEx".
"merging menus" is not the problem, but then how to use "ShellExecuteEx" on multiple files?

f.e. if i have 6 files and click on "7-zip -> archiv and send" in explorer then 7-zip is called only once with all 6 files. how does explorer do this?

If I call 6 times "ShellExecuteEx" like in the examples in the web it will result in 6 seperate archive files with each containing only 1 file and 6 archive files will be sent.

please, how to solve that?

Sample code (little bit changed from https://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=25228):

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
    shellapi,
    ShlObj,
    comobj, activex,
    Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes;

procedure ContextMenuForFileList(
                            X, Y : Integer; Handle : HWND;
                            lst:TStrings
                        );

implementation

function        SHParseDisplayName(
                        pszName:    PWideChar;  //  PCWSTR           pszName,
                        const pbc:      IBindCtx;   //      IBindCtx    *pbc,
                        var ppidl:  PItemIDList;                            //  PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE *ppidl,
                        sfgaoIn:            DWORD;          //SFGAOF           sfgaoIn,
                        var psfgaoOut:  DWORD       //SFGAOF           *psfgaoOut
                        ):HResult;  stdcall;    external 'Shell32.dll';


function        SHGetIDListFromPath( v:WideString):PItemIDList; // ShellFolder);
var
    sfgaoIn:            uint;
    sfgaoOut:       uint;
begin
    sfgaoIn:=   0;
    sfgaoOut:=  0;
    OleCheck(
                SHParseDisplayName(
                        PWideChar( v),
                        nil,
                        Result,
                        sfgaoIn,
                        sfgaoOut
                        )
                );
end;

procedure ContextMenuForFileList(
                            X, Y : Integer; Handle : HWND;
                            lst:TStrings
                        );
var
    aContextMenu:   IContextMenu;
    aPrgOut:            Pointer;
    aPopup:         HMENU;
    aCmd:               Integer;
    aCmdInfo:       TCMInvokeCommandInfo;
    ShellFolder:    IShellFolder;
    I, Cnt:         integer;
    PIDL:               array of PItemIDList;
begin
    Cnt := lst.Count;
    SetLength(PIDL, Cnt);
    for I := 0 to Cnt - 1 do begin
//////
//      PIDL[I] := SHGetIDListFromPath(lst[I], ShellFolder);
        PIDL[I] := SHGetIDListFromPath( lst[I]);
        if I<Cnt - 1 then
//          ShellFolder.Release;
        ShellFolder:=   nil;
    end;

    OleCheck( SHGetDesktopFolder( ShellFolder));

    for I := 0 to Cnt - 1 do
        if not Assigned(PIDL[I]) then Exit;  {Here we would need to free data...}

    aPrgOut := nil;

    OLECheck(ShellFolder.GetUIObjectOf(0, Cnt, PIDL[0],
                                IID_IContextMenu, aPrgOut, Pointer(aContextMenu)));

    aPopup := CreatePopUpMenu;
    if aPopup = 0 then Exit;

    try
        OLECheck(aContextMenu.QueryContextMenu(aPopup, 0, 1, $7FFF, CMF_NORMAL));
        aCmd := Integer(TrackPopupMenuEx(aPopup,
                        TPM_LEFTALIGN or TPM_RETURNCMD
                        or TPM_RIGHTBUTTON or TPM_HORIZONTAL
                        or TPM_VERTICAL, X, Y, Handle, nil));
        if aCmd <> 0 then begin
            FillChar(aCmdInfo, Sizeof(aCmdInfo), 0);
            with aCmdInfo do begin
                cbSize := SizeOf(TCMInvokeCommandInfo);
                lpVerb := MakeIntResourceA(aCmd - 1);
                nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
            end;
            try
                aContextMenu.InvokeCommand(aCmdInfo);
            except
            end;
        end;
    finally
        DestroyMenu(aPopup);
    end;
end;

end.

{in the main unit:}
procedure   TFormMain.Test;
var
    lst:    TStringList;
begin
    lst:=   TStringList.Create;
    try
        lst.Add(    'C:\temp\test.pdf');
        ContextMenuForFileList(
            0,  //X,
            0,  //Y : Integer;
            Handle,
            lst
        );
    finally
        lst.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Testing this code with the only one pdf-file in the list, I get a menu that does not contain "Open Adobe ...", but I get Items which are ONLY(!) defined for directories (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folders), but should not appear for files.

=========================

Update:

=========================

after inserting code that maps "pidl" to a relative path

```
_root.ParseDisplayName( ...,  <directory of file>, .. _par_PIDL )
_root.BindToObject( _par_PIDL, ... _iDir);
_idir.ParseDisplayName( ... <file_name_without_path> ..., new_pidl)
```

and fill the array with the new_pidl, but calling "_root.GetUIObjectOf( ..." on root, I got it to work, that the menu is shown with all items.

But "Open Adobe..." failed with "could not find file".
Testing with "C:\temp\folder1\a.bmp" and pressing "open", paint shows "can't open file C:\users\heinz\a.bmp".

Maybe the reason:

"SHGetDesktopFolder( _Root)" should return the top most "IShellFolder" where all drives and files on computer can be reached, right?
Indeed, inspecting the pidl of _root,

```
var
    _fld:   IPersistFolder2;
begin
    _fld:=  _root as IPersistFolder2;
    OleCheck( _fld.GetCurFolder( root_pidl));
```

the root_pidl is empty.
but testing to which path this "empty ItemIDList" belongs with

```
SHGetPathFromIDListA( root_pidl, buf)
```

then I get my local user path: C:\users\heinz
but not something like a real root "".

=========================

Update 2:

=========================

After more investigations I found the following link:
https://www.zabkat.com/blog/08Jul07.htm

It explains the problem and gave me helpful informations. Adapted the code in Delphi and tried. A step further, but not more.
It sounds so easy only to provide an array with correct extensions for the file, f.e "HKCR\.pdf" for PDF-Files. What else? Didn't work.

Tried also others like "HKCR\ADOBE.Document.0", but didn't get menu item "Open Adobe ...".

=========================

Update 3: (extended to c++, maybe that experts can help)

=========================

Somehow it must be able to do this, because you can select some different files in explorer, if you select a top level directory, search for '*.pdf' in the search field and select some pdf-files from different sub-directories.
then all works as expected.

In a program I read the IDataObject which Explorer provides in both cases and found out:

1. if selecting only 1 file in explorer, then method "GetData()" returns (beside CF_HDROP, ...) also cfFormat of CF_SHELLIDLIST and with the parentpidl or pidl calling function "SHGetPathFromIDListA()" gives me the correct file paths.
2. if selecting multiple files in explorer search view, then method "GetData()" returns also cfFormat of CF_SHELLIDLIST, but "SHGetPathFromIDListA()" crashes on both, parentpidl or pidl.

But you can call SHCreateItemFromIDList() with refiid of "IUnknown" for both pidls. Also _shitm=Queryinterface() for "IShellItem" returns S_OK for both pids.

_shitm.GetDisplayName( SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING, ..) returns
'Searchresults in "dbg"&"*.pdf"
for parentpidl,

but fail on the pidls for the files.

=========================

Update 4:

=========================

After all I ended up in build the whole menu by myself.